# RUN POWERSHELL cmd in Docker build fails with error - 'returned a non-zero code: 3221226505'

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, windows-server-2016

Host running docker is windows 2016

OS Name: Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter (Version 1607)

OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393.3504

The Docker build started to fail all of a sudden. This was working until few days ago. Sometimes it starts to work again on its own.. Once we restart the host server or the cache is lost - it starts throwing this error.  After some time it starts to work again.. really unpredictable. Can someone help?

```
Step 1/26 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016 AS base
 ---> c5037b311625
Step 2/26 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f84175a68324
Step 3/26 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a72ee1dd6763
Step 4/26 : RUN PowerShell Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force;[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;$env:chocolateyUseWindowsCompression = 'true'; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
 ---> Running in 0d15f930ea0d
compose.cli.main.main: Service 'someabc' failed to build: The command 'cmd /S /C PowerShell Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force;[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;$env:chocolateyUseWindowsCompression = 'true'; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))' returned a non-zero code: 3221226505
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: any pointers pls? this has become a big problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is 0xC0000409 ERROR_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN. The irony that you are that you asking this on Stack Overflow. This is a memory leak or a stack overflow.

System.Net.WebClient can only be called so many times before you run out of memory resources. I added $webc.dispose() to ASK the garbage collection clean up.  The start-sleep gives the garbage collector time to do the clean up.  If it continues to break increase the sleep time.

```
cmd /S /C PowerShell Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force;[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;$env:chocolateyUseWindowsCompression = 'true'; iex ((($Webc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1')));$Webc.dispose() ; Start-Sleep 1
```

The reason that it starts to working again is the script crashes then .net is then allowed to dispose of System.Net.WebClient.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didnt work. i get this error

Step 5/30 : 
 ---> Running in 456b372cf6b2
ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: Service 'someabc' failed to build: The command 'cmd /S /C PowerShell Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force;[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;$env:chocolateyUseWindowsCompression = 'true'; iex ((($Webc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1')));$Webc.dispose() ; Start-Sleep 1' returned a non-zero code: 255